# Sensors TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD - They work on phones, but doesn't on tablets

Tags: android, android-sensors

In my 2d game I have the following code which is responsible for game entity control (flying plane). It all seems to be working fine when it comes for phones, but unfortunately I've getting some information that on Android tablets the steering is completely unreliable (axis are messed up, or it doesn't work at all). Unfortunately I don't have a tablet of my own, so I cannot investigate it closer. So.. what's wrong with the following code? (for the clarity I put only the code related to sensors)

```
// ...
private float[] accelerometerValues;
private float[] magneticFieldValues;
private float[] R;
private float[] I;
private float[] outR;
private float[] sensorValues;

private Sensor accelerometer;
private Sensor magneticField;
// ...

// ... sensor initialization
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if(sensorManager == null)
        return;
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER); 
    magneticField = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
// ...

// ... onPause() sensor is being unregistered
public void onResume() {
    if(!sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME) ||
       !sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, magneticField, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME))
// ...

    // ...
    sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {              
        }
        public void onSensorChanged(android.hardware.SensorEvent event) {
            synchronized(InputMgr.this) {
                switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, accelerometerValues, 0, 3);
                    break;
                case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magneticFieldValues, 0, 3);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };  
    // ...  

    // used somewhere in the game
public void getSensorValues(float values[]) {
    synchronized(InputMgr.this) {
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, accelerometerValues, magneticFieldValues);
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_X, outR);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, sensorValues);
        System.arraycopy(sensorValues, 0, values, 0, sensorValues.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot help you on the matter, but I can confirm that some differences exists between phones and some tablets. I have a game installed on my HTC Desire (android 2.3) that uses orientation sensor control and it works perfectly well, but the same game on my Asus Transformer Prime (android 4.0.3) does not work at all. The orientation control goes bananas. Dont know if its related to android version or tablet itself, but something is not the same.

Comment: Yes this didn't help at all, but maybe I can help you in your case. Probably you shouldn't use TYPE_ORIENTATION, as it is deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ORIENTATION

Comment: Well, its not my game, but I can send an email to the developer of that game. Thanks.

Comment: As you don't give much info about the rest of your code - depending on which sensors models are available on the device, events delays aren't the same. Some devices will provide synchronized events (ex : Galaxy Tab 10.1 that will give you ~10ms delay for each sensor) and others won't (ex : Galaxy Tab 7 that might give you MAGNETIC_FIELD values 3 times slower than ACCELEROMETER ones). This might not be a problem in your case however. 3D referentials are similar for each device though (same conventions, same axis).

Comment: I've updated the source code from the question. This is pretty much it, no more sensor's code there. In my game I'm using getSensorValues(float []) to acquire all necessary information.
I'm still investigating the problem, but I'm really out of ideas now. Maybe something related to calibration (pure guess)?

Comment: I've been briefly looking at codes available on the internet and one thing came to my mind. In my code I use System.arraycopy() to copy the sensor's values to my temporary float array (I did that because I didn't want to dynamically allocate the new memory chunk). In the code snippets that I've found on the internet the event.values.clone() is rather used. May it be that there is some low level problem in my code, float alignments etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On devices whose default orientation is landscape (-> most tablets), the sensor values are kind of 'wrong' (I don't know why). So you need to catch those devices and remap your Rotation Matrix.

To check whether the matrix needs to be remapped, you can use this code:

```
public boolean needToRemapOrientationMatrix;

// compute once (e.g. in onCreate() of your Activity):
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int orientation;
if(display.getWidth() < display.getHeight()) orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
else if(display.getWidth() > display.getHeight()) orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
else orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
int rotation = display.getRotation();
needToRemapOrientationMatrix =
    (orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && (rotation==Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation==Surface.ROTATION_180)) ||
    (orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT && (rotation==Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation==Surface.ROTATION_270));
```

And when you read the sensor values, remap the matrix if needed:

```
public void getSensorValues(float values[]) {
    synchronized(InputMgr.this) {
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, accelerometerValues, magneticFieldValues);

        if(needToRemapOrientationMatrix)
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_X, R);

        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_X, outR);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, sensorValues);
        System.arraycopy(sensorValues, 0, values, 0, sensorValues.length);
    }
}
```

This worked for me, I hope it helps.

Comment: I will have to get a tablet device first and than I'll check it. It's definitely worth trying. Fnx

Comment: @cplusogl I just found this code: http://code.google.com/p/androgames-sample/source/browse/Market-apps/Level/trunk/src/net/androgames/level/orientation/provider/ProviderAccelerometer.java?spec=svn76&r=76 You may have a look how the matrix is handled there.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been trying to fix tablets all morning, this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

This wont cheer you up much but I have a similar problem. I can see a TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD sensor, I can add a an event listener to it but I never get any data from it. Other sensors work fine. This is on a Galaxy Tab 7.

onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) never fires a  case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:

As such I get no data from the Magnetic Field Sensor.

if you solve it let us know =)

Comment: Same sh~t here! Works flawlessly on Nexus S(4.3), Tab2(4.4.4), but no magnetometer updates on Asus tablet(4.1.2) and Galaxy S3(4.3)!